# Cancel Tap gesture on UIBarbutton in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uigesturerecognizer

I have added Tap Gesture recognizer to a view. My view has an image and a UIToolBar at the bottom with a few UIBarbuttons I want to cancel any touches on these buttons. I am trying to use the following method to cancel the touch. How do I detect whether the touch is on the toolbar or any bar buttons? Frame is also not defined for Bar buttons...

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {


    if (gestureRecognizer == tapRecognizer) {
  if (touch.view==barbutton/*toolbar or bar button item*/) 
   {
   return NO;   
  }

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
if(CGRectContainsPoint(toolbar.frame, location)) { ... }
```

This is assuming the toolbar and `self.view` are in the same coordinate space. If not, you'll have to use UIView's coordinate conversion methods (`convertPoint:toView:`) to make the spaces match.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are the first responder and their uitouchup or other event will fire first and won't propogate to the backing view.

You can subclass your buttons and have the touchesbegan/moved/ended do:

```
[self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

to have your backing view handle all their events for them in which case your gesture code should work.